# Как работать с txt файлом как с массивом?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть текстовый файл, в нём хранятся данные в таком формате:

```
#31~Страна~
        @135~Город1~
            $8~Тип1
            $1~Тип2
        @136~Город2~
            $8~Тип1
            $15~Тип3
```

Формат файла менять нельзя. 
Как реализовать работу с данным тхт файлом, как с массивом?

Тоесть в форме выбирается страна. Идёт проверка в файле по этой стране и если есть данные (город), то создаётся селект с выбором города. При выборе города, проверка в файле и вывод Типа.

Естественно не решение нужно, а при помощи чего реализовать? а то я в полном ступоре, не пойму с чего начать. Спасибо

Comment: А файл вы откуда берете?

Comment: Парсинг структуры в селекторы по глубине; при выборе предка, извлекать подходящего потомка. Просто же.

Comment: @Bleser файл мне предоставляют. В нём ничего править нельзя

Comment: @Other Не очень понятно) можете на элементарном примере показать? спасибо

Comment: Требуйте чтобы данные предоставляли в формате json, раз уж ваша программа написана на js. А это какая-то белиберда, а не формат. Не кошерно!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, мысль понятна:

```js
let db = `#31~Страна~
@135~Город1~
$8~Тип1
$1~Тип2
@136~Город2~
$8~Тип1
$15~Тип3`;
let countries = {};
let cities = {};
let types = {};

db.split("\n").reduce((p, s) => {
  let [, num, name] = s.match(/(\d+)~([^~]+)/);
  
  switch (s.trim().charAt(0)) {
    case '#':
      p.co = num;
      countries[num] = name;
      break;
    case '@':
      p.ci = num;
      if (!(p.co in cities)) cities[p.co] = [];
      cities[p.co].push([p.ci, name]);
      break;
    case '$':
      p.ty = num;
      if (!(p.ci in types)) types[p.ci] = [];
      types[p.ci].push([p.ty, name]);
      break;
  }
  
  return p;
}, {co: null, ci: null, ty: null});

V = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    country: -1,
    city: -1,
    type: -1
  }
});
```

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' v-cloak>
  <select v-model="country">
    <option disabled value="-1">Pick your option here</option>
    <option v-for="(name, key) in countries" :key="key" :value="key">{{ name }}</option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="city" v-if="country in cities">
    <option disabled value="-1">Pick your option here</option>
    <option v-for="(city, key) in cities[country]" :key="city[0]" :value="city[0]">{{ city[1] }}</option>
  </select>
  <select v-model="type" v-if="city in types">
    <option disabled value="-1">Pick your option here</option>
    <option v-for="(type, key) in types[city]" :key="type[0]" :value="type[0]">{{ type[1] }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я набросал код, который помещает в массив страны - отдельно код, отдельно название - и всю мешанину городов. Я могу и города обработать, если надо - но просто думаю, что в коротком коде легче видна суть. Если надо и города - мне нетрудно

```
    var txt ='#31~Страна~        @135~Город1~            $8~Тип1            $1~Тип2        @136~Город2~            $8~Тип1            $15~Тип3#31~Страна~        @135~Город1~            $8~Тип1            $1~Тип2        @136~Город2~            $8~Тип1            $15~Тип3';

var re1 = /#\d+~[А-Яа-я]+~[^#]+/g;
var re2 = /#(\d+)~([А-Яа-я]+)~([^#]+)/;

var massiv = []; //Массив, в который преобразуем текст 

if(re1.test(txt))
{
    var m1= txt.match(re1); //массив подстрок, соотв. странам
    for(var i = 0; i < m1.length; i++)
    {
        var oneCountry = m1[i];
        var m2 = oneCountry.match(re2); //разбор одной страны
        massiv[i] = { 'countryCode': m2[1] , 'counrtyName': m2[2], 'cities' : m2[3] };
    }

console.log(massiv); 

}
```